# Extract a feature from a shapefile layer, rasterize it and save to a numpy array

Tags: python, raster, gdal, features, numpy

I have the following problem:

The following sequence of operations:

1. loading a `shp` file using a `gdal` package,
2. extracting a layer out of it (every feature in this layer is a polygon),

leads me to a place where rasterizing every feature in its own extent to a separate `numpy.array` seems to be an impossible task.

Is there any way to achieve that without hacking a `osg` package in a really cumbersome way?

Comment: You can extract and combine what you want from a Numpy array (Map algebra)

Comment: Goodday everyone. Pls, I would like to create an offline android app that can read arcmap (arcgis) shapefiles and generate the maps as created on arcgis. I tend using python for it. How do I go about it? Thanks in anticipation

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/163055)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `fiona` to read the shapefile, and `rasterio` to rasterize the geometries.
The example below returns a list of numpy arrays containing each the rasterized output the feature.

```
import urllib
import zipfile

import fiona
from rasterio import features
from affine import Affine

# Download data
urllib.urlretrieve("http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2.8/shp/BLZ_adm_shp.zip", "belize.zip")

# Extract data
with zipfile.ZipFile('belize.zip', 'r') as con:
    con.extractall()

# Read shapefile and raterize each of its features
with fiona.open('BLZ_adm1.shp') as src:
    np_list = [features.rasterize([geom['geometry']], out_shape=(500,500), transform=Affine(0.01, 0.0, -90.0, 0, -0.01, 18.0)) for geom in src]
```

To have them all in a single 3D array

```
import numpy as np

with fiona.open('BLZ_adm1.shp') as src:
    # Preallocate array
    geom_np = np.zeros((500, 500, len(src)), dtype = np.int8)
    for id, geom in enumerate(src):
        geom_np[:,:,id] = features.rasterize([geom['geometry']], out_shape=(500,500), transform=Affine(0.01, 0.0, -90.0, 0, -0.01, 18.0))
```

If you have a 'matching' image you would probably use its `shape` and `transform` instead of those I arbitrarily defined in the example.